# Create a list of objects by grouping on multiple properties

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a `List<T>` where `T` is a custom object `Cow`. Right now I use the following code to split that list up based on `Color`.

```
cowGroups = from x in cows
            group x by x.Color into y
            select y.ToList().ToList();
```

Then I take `cowGroups` and run a `foreach` on it to do a set of actions to each `Cow`. This list actually comes out as `IEnumerable<List<Cow>>`

What I'm trying to do is do a double grouping on my initial `List<Cow>` so that I can group base on their color and size. The result should still be `IEnumerable<List<Cow>>`, but each `List<Cow>` would be made based on the combined pair of color and size.

A co-worker recommended a `ToLookup` approach, but that returns a list of key/value pairs, and I can't seem to do anything with the value part of the pair.

I guess I'm looking for either a way to go straight to a collection of lists, or turn the result of the `ToLookup` approach into a collection of lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can group by a class that contains both attributes:

```
group x by new { x.Color, x.Size } into y
```

Comment: Oh my... I feel so stupid now. One of the things I had tried was `cows.GroupBy(new {x.Color, x.Size}) but it resulted in a similar structure as ToLookup. **EDIT**: I should add that this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!